# vegan package specaccum - Error in colSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to use a taxonomy file to run a species curve using the package `vegan` and the function `specaccum`, but I keep getting the error:

```
Error in colSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric
```

This file is a huge table, with species taxonomy in the first column, and sites in the next ones. Like this:

```
sum.taxonomy | K0024.A2.S1.L001.x | K0024.B2.S9.L001.x
Acantharea;Arthracanthida;Acanthometridae;Acanthometra; | 0 | 57
Acantharea;Chaunacanthida;NA;; | 3 | 0
```

Each value is a number corresponding to the number of reads. I've tried uploading this file in multiple ways, I've looked for missing values, I've tried forcing the table `as.numeric` and still no success.

This is the command I thought would work:

```
    table <- read.table("All_reads_all_markers_all_samples_after_decontamination.txt", 
             header = TRUE, sep = "\t",  quote = "", comment.char = "", 
             row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)
    specaccum(table, method = "rarefaction")
```

I don't know what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using RStudio v1.1.383, R v3.5.0, and vegan v2.5.1 in a Windows 10.

Comment: How did you go from `table` to `test`? Please share your data so others can help (post the outputs from `dput(table)` & `dput(test))

Comment: You really should not argue with a computer: Computer is much more pedantic than you, and if it finds non-numeric data, then you have non-numeric data. Your task is only to find that conflicting item yourself.

Comment: Check out the structure of table and test with `str(table)` or as @Tung mentioned, with `dput()`. If you see that a column is not numeric, although it should be, you have to convert it to numeric -> `table$variable <- as.numeric(table$variable)`

Comment: NB, `as.numeric()`  only changes factors to numeric, but you read your non-numeric data as characters (`stringAsFactors = FALSE)`. These cannot be turned into numeric. OTOH, you should not turn factors to numeric either, because this makes no sense in `specaccum`. You got to find the columns that really should be numeric and take care that they are numeric, and correct numbers, too.

Comment: sorry, @Tung, that was a typo! and you were right! there was a stupid `'` inside a single cell from the more the 20000 ones, that with the help of a friend we were able to track down. we did the following: `ttt=apply(table,MARGIN = 1:2,FUN = as.numeric)`, then `which(is.na(ttt[,1]))` we changed the column numbers decreasingly from 150 to 1 (of course it was on the last one), and then searched the row in that column. not fun! :(